# Is it possible to automatically map and define HashSets as virtual with Scaffold-DbContext command?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my app, I'm using EF Core with Lazy Loading. Since Lazy Loading requires all HashSets to be defined as `virtual`, after executing `Scaffold-DbContext` command to map a DB, I've always edited all single generated file in order to copy-paste the "`virtual`" keyword before every single `ICollection<ClassA>`, etc...

In small-DB case, this is not a very time-expensive operation, but it becomes more long-timed as the mapped db grows in terms of number of tables and relations between tables.

So the question is: is there any way to automatically map all HashSets as `virtual` since the first execution of `Scaffold-DbContext` command?

 Or does it already exist any way to automatically do this operation once the database has been mapped?

Comment: please add some code I'm not sure that understand you, when scaffolding is interesting topic for me.